# Mixing contracted and uncontracted phrases in the same sentence

Tags: grammaticality, contractions

Is there anything wrong with mixing contracted with uncontracted phrases in the same sentence?

Examples:

> **I'm** not sure **it is** possible.

("I'm" is contracted, but "it is" is not).

> I **am not** sure **it's** possible.

("I am" is not contracted, but "it's" is).

I know that it is not grammatically incorrect. But is it not recommended?  Or is there any other reason to not use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there anything wrong with mixing contracted with uncontracted phrases in the same sentence?

No, there isn't. You can freely write a word contracting it, and write another one without to contract it.
As reported by Mr. Shiny and New, sometimes a word is written without to contract it to put emphasize on it.

Answer (score 2):

One valid use is when you want to emphasize one word:

> I am **NOT** sure it's possible

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anything wrong with mixing contracted with uncontracted
>   phrases in the same sentence?

It's perfectly fine to mix contracted and uncontracted forms and you find occurrences of it in reliable sources, but the tendency is to be consistent.

[Take a look at the examples here](https://ludwig.guru/s/I'm+not+sure+it+is+possible).

> I'm not sure it is possible to think too much. (The Guardian)

and

> I'm not sure it's possible to be anything but naive when moving abroad. (The Guardian)

*Full disclosure, I work at [Ludwig.guru](https://ludwig.guru/)*

Comment: FYI, Stack Exchange [has detailed guidelines](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) on how to refer to your own stuff in answers (including your employer). You've done it right, for the record, but I wanted to explicitly link them so you have something to refer to if you need them.

Comment: I amended the link. Is it fine now?

Comment: I mean, it was fine before, too, but yes, it continues to be fine now :)